# What distribution has the probability generating function $\mathbb E[s^X]=\left(\frac{1-\delta P}{1-sP}\right)^{\frac{1-s}{\delta-s}}$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, generating-functions

Is it possible to obtain the probability mass function for the discrete random variable $X$ associated with the following probability generating function?

$$
\mathbb E[s^X]=\left(\frac{1-\delta P}{1-sP}\right)^{\frac{1-s}{\delta-s}}
$$

In the limit $\delta\to1$, this is the generating function of the Geometric($P$) distribution, which models the number of successes before the first failure given a success probability $P$. It would be great to obtain the distribution of $X$ for any $0<\delta<1$, or at least some sort of asymptotic expansion about $\delta\approx 1$. Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I think the math here is interesting but it's not clear what you're really asking. The title seems to be asking "is there a commonly accepted name for this distribution", which is a legitimate question (too bad I don't know the answer to). However, the first sentence "Is it possible to obtain the mass function..." is kind of strange, since you seem to know the the definition of probability generating function and should be able to calculate any specific term you want.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin, thanks for pointing this out. Of course, one can in principle calculate the probability that $X$ takes on any specific value using the property that $\mathbb{P}(X=x)=\frac{1}{x!}\frac{\partial^x}{\partial^x s}\mathbb{E}[s^X]|_{s=0}$. It would be nice, however, to have a general expression for this that is not in terms of an $x^{\text{th}}$ derivative. This is possible if $\delta=1$, in which case I believe $\mathbb{P}(X=x) = (1-P)P^x$.